# Searching for copied files, while ignoring the file name

Tags: bash

Sometimes my students try to submit identical files for their homework. If they did their homework themselves, it would be impossible for any two files to be the exactly the same.

I put the homework in folders arranged like this: `/section/id/`

In this way, each section of the course has its own folder, each student has their own folder, and all of the files are within that last level. The student files come in a variety of formats.

- How can I check if there are any exactly identical files (ignoring file names) within any sub-folder?

Comment: Eh, this sounds like a homework question. What have you tried?

Comment: Betty's answer solves your problem, but I reckon it'd be very easily circumventable... You might want to consider [more advanced pagarism detection](http://www.ics.heacademy.ac.uk/resources/assessment/plagiarism/detectiontools_sourcecode.html).

Comment: How it is possible, that they will always not be the same ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can help you identify exact same files from your students using the following `for loop` and `awk` one-liner:

**Step: 1** - `for i in path/to/files; do cksum "$i"; done > cksum.txt`
**Step: 2** - `awk 'NR==FNR && a[$1]++ { b[$1]; next } $1 in b' cksum.txt cksum.txt`

**Test:**

#### Some sample files in which `student 2` has used identical file as `student 1`

```
[jaypal:~/Temp/homework] ls -lrt
total 32
-rw-r--r--  1 jaypalsingh  staff  10 17 Dec 17:58 student1
-rw-r--r--  1 jaypalsingh  staff  10 17 Dec 17:58 student2
-rw-r--r--  1 jaypalsingh  staff  10 17 Dec 17:58 student3
-rw-r--r--  1 jaypalsingh  staff  10 17 Dec 17:58 student4
[jaypal:~/Temp/homework] cat student1 
homework1
[jaypal:~/Temp/homework] cat student2 
homework1
[jaypal:~/Temp/homework] cat student3 
homework3
[jaypal:~/Temp/homework] cat student4 
homework4
```

**Step 1:**

#### Create a cksum.txt file using the `cksum` utility

```
[jaypal:~/Temp/homework] for i in *; do cksum "$i"; done > cksum.txt
[jaypal:~/Temp/homework] cat cksum.txt 
4294967295 0 cksum.txt
1271506813 10 student1
1271506813 10 student2
1215889011 10 student3
1299429862 10 student4
```

**Step 2:**

#### Using `awk` one-liner identify all files that are same

```
[jaypal:~/Temp/homework] awk 'NR==FNR && a[$1]++ { b[$1]; next } $1 in b' cksum.txt cksum.txt 
1271506813 10 student1
1271506813 10 student2
```

**Test 2:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp/homework] for i in stu*; do cksum "$i"; done > cksum.txt
[jaypal:~/Temp/homework] awk 'NR==FNR && a[$1]++ { b[$1]; next } $1 in b' cksum.txt cksum.txt 
1271506813 10 student1
1271506813 10 student2
1271506813 10 student5
[jaypal:~/Temp/homework] cat student5
homework1
```

Comment: Don't know if it would be accurate though. Even a space in identical files throws it off. So his students can continue to cheat and not get caught as long as they add a new line!! :)

Comment: The accuracy level is good. Most students do not take the time to change the files and in some cases, it is difficult for them to change it, as some required work is multimedia. Simply checking for duplicates will remove most of the cheaters and save me many hours of time in grading.

Comment: Does this check if only 2 files are the same? Sometimes there might be 3 or more that are identical.

Comment: No this will list out all the files that have the same first column which is the cksum. So if you have 10 files that have same cksum then all of them will be listed out. You may have to pipe it to sort to get everything in order. Have added a test.

Answer (score 3):

Create an md5 of all the files and insert them into a dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

To list those files that have at least one duplicate:

```
md5sum * | sort | uniq -w32 --all-repeat=separate | awk '{print $2}'
```

Of course, this only finds files that are *completely* identical.

To deal with things in subfolders, you'll want to modify it to work with `find`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a whole field of study:

- [Plagiarism detection](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FPlagiarism_detection&ei=zTjtToOaMMmj-gagmZiKAg&usg=AFQjCNHBK7vi0Qo4JFftzq3x55_KpRUfuw)
- other (will search later)

The thing with the mentioned approaches is, that changes in the tab size/settings and stuff like that will make a difference. Most homework assignments even require the student's name at the top. That will make all identical submissions look different.

I suggest running the submission throught the preprocessor (stripping comments, for one thing) and through some (very strict) code indenter (astyle, bcpp, cindent...?) to remove any 'superficial differences'.

You might even want to consider ignoring case - if you allow some false positives. This would even be able to spot the plagiarizer with a taste for naming conventions (renaming `FindSpork()` to `findSpork()`?).

There is a number of heuristics I could think of to add. This should set you off in the right direction, though.

**Edit** P.S. of course after anything else, you can still run it through a checksum. So e.g. you could do

```
cat submission.cpp | astyle -bj | cpp - | md5sum
```

to get something of fingerprint that is far less sensitive to *accidental/superficial* changes (like, comments or whitespace).

Answer (score 2):

If you are really interested in exact copies, group files by size. If a group has more than one member, run `md5sum` on the files and then `sort | uniq -c` to see whether there are duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

[fdupes](http://premium.caribe.net/~adrian2/fdupes.html) works well here for this task

Answer (score 0):

The following will detect if they've simply renamed a bunch of variables and changed things like whitespace and tabs.

```
#!/bin/bash
separate=$(for f; do gzip -9 -c < "$f"; done | wc -c)
together=$(cat "$@" | gzip -9 -c | wc -c)
echo "$separate / $together = $((separate*100/together))%"
```

This technique is referred to as "Compression-Based Dissimilarity". See [Text Comparison Using Data Compression](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/289189224_Text_comparison_using_data_compression):

> Similarity detection is very important in the field of spam detection, plagiarism detection or topic detection. The main algorithm for comparison of text document is based on the Kolmogorov Complexity, which is one of the perfect measures for computation of the similarity of two strings in defined alphabet. Unfortunately, this measure is incomputable and we must define several approximations which are not metric at all, but in some circumstances are close to this behaviour and may be used in practice.
>
> (PDF) Text comparison using data compression. Available from: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/289189224_Text_comparison_using_data_compression [accessed Sep 13 2018].